# Login failed in Spotify Android SDK tutorial

Tags: android, spotify

I'm trying to complete the beginner's tutorial for android sdk. I've made all the passage and no build errors occours, however launching the app, when I try to authenticate with facebook, in the logcat, I found "login failed"

```
06-21 18:34:39.282  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/MainActivity﹕ Login failed
```

Here the complete log

```
06-21 18:34:34.642  14033-14033/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
06-21 18:34:34.877  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-21 18:34:34.897  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-21 18:34:34.902  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
06-21 18:34:34.907  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/﹕ Device driver API match
    Device driver API version: 10
    User space API version: 10
06-21 18:34:34.907  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/﹕ mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012
06-21 18:34:34.932  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
06-21 18:34:35.032  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova I/webclipboard﹕ clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41b7b0d0
06-21 18:34:35.112  14033-14034/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 158K, 13% free 9649K/11079K, paused 14ms+12ms, total 45ms
06-21 18:34:35.117  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/WebView﹕ loadUrlImpl: called
06-21 18:34:35.137  14033-14050/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova V/webkit﹕ BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {41b75b88}
06-21 18:34:35.182  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/WebView﹕ onSizeChanged - w:442 h:724
06-21 18:34:35.187  14033-14050/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/webcore﹕ CORE loadUrl: called
06-21 18:34:35.187  14033-14050/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/webkit﹕ Firewall not null
06-21 18:34:35.192  14033-14050/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/webkit﹕ euler: isUrlBlocked = false
06-21 18:34:35.332  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova W/ResourceType﹕ Failure getting entry for 0x010802c0 (t=7 e=704) in package 0 (error -75)
06-21 18:34:35.382  14033-14034/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 109K, 13% free 9945K/11335K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 44ms
06-21 18:34:38.377  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/WebCore﹕ uiOverrideUrlLoading: shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returnstrue
06-21 18:34:38.377  14033-14050/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova I/GATE﹕ <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
06-21 18:34:38.432  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS
06-21 18:34:38.432  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 78 (SUPPORTED_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
06-21 18:34:38.432  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
06-21 18:34:38.432  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_ABIS
06-21 18:34:38.432  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x004e at 0x17 in Lcom/spotify/sdk/android/player/Config;.createOsVersionString
06-21 18:34:38.442  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova W/ApplicationContext﹕ Unable to create external files directory
06-21 18:34:38.452  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.media.AudioTrack.setVolume, referenced from method com.spotify.sdk.android.player.AudioTrackController.createAudioTrack
06-21 18:34:38.452  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 694: Landroid/media/AudioTrack;.setVolume (F)I
06-21 18:34:38.452  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x004c
06-21 18:34:38.457  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x41b2f108
06-21 18:34:38.457  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x41b2f108
06-21 18:34:38.457  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0x41b2f108, skipping init
06-21 18:34:38.457  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova/lib/libspotify_embedded_shared.so 0x41b2f108
06-21 18:34:38.462  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova/lib/libspotify_embedded_shared.so 0x41b2f108
06-21 18:34:38.462  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova/lib/libspotify_embedded_shared.so 0x41b2f108, skipping init
06-21 18:34:38.462  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib /data/data/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova/lib/libspotify_sdk.so 0x41b2f108
06-21 18:34:38.462  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/data/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova/lib/libspotify_sdk.so 0x41b2f108
06-21 18:34:38.507  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-21 18:34:38.507  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
06-21 18:34:38.527  14033-14120/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/SpotifySDK﹕ Use diskcache: true
06-21 18:34:38.527  14033-14120/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova E/SpotifySDK﹕ Cache path '' is not writeable
06-21 18:34:38.532  14033-14120/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova I/SpotifySDK﹕ Got notification: Became active playing device
06-21 18:34:38.532  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/MainActivity﹕ Playback event received: BECAME_ACTIVE
06-21 18:34:38.532  14033-14120/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova I/SpotifySDK﹕ playbackCallbackOnSeek (to 0ms)
06-21 18:34:39.282  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/MainActivity﹕ Login failed
06-21 18:35:17.487  14033-14034/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 207K, 13% free 10160K/11655K, paused 8ms+12ms, total 92ms
06-21 18:35:17.492  14033-14033/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/webviewglue﹕ nativeDestroy view: 0x4db6e608
```

Any idea to fix this issue? I've already try to delete the app from my facebook account but nothig, always "Login failed"

**Update 1**

I've print the message of the exception lauch the onLoginFailed method:

```
06-21 18:53:59.362  28201-28201/com.example.lucabrognara.spotify_prova D/MainActivity﹕ Login failed: The operation requires a Spotify Premium account
```

I'm not sure why for login I need a premium account...

**Update 2**

I've explicitally asked for a test account and [the answer](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/127), I guess, close this question:

Q: "There's a way to use a test account? I'm developing an android app and i need spotify authentication"

A: "@lucabro no, I'm afraid you need to have a Spotify Premium account to be able to use this SDK"

Comment: I think you should file this in the [Spotify Android SDK GitHub project](https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk).

Answer (score 1):

Spotify doesn't seem to allow free users, not sure though

EDIT: Yeah they do need a premium account as of now, as you found out.

https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/49

Comment: Full playback is not available for non-premium users, but login should work for all users.

Comment: I really implemented only the tutorial app, nothing more, and for that app seems need a premium...
The app should allow to authenticate and play a track when login succeded...

Answer (score 0):

Spotify API access has different scopes to gather information , and one or more of them , need premium account. I think you should be trying to access the scope " streaming ," which is premium .

Check your line :

```
builder.setScopes (new String [ ] { "scopeexample1", "scopeexample2" } ) ;
```